# Provide a link order for `.so` libraries

Tags: linux, centos, shared-library, dynamic-linking

I need to dynamically link to a number of `.so` shared libraries from R. R can only do this one at a time using the `dyn.load` function, which takes the file path of the shared object. However, if the shared library that I load has dependencies on another shared library that I haven't already loaded, then the linking will fail.

Thus, I need to obtain a topological sort of the dependencies of a list of shared libraries so I can link them in the correct order. I realise that I *can* extract this information by running `ldd` on each shared library and parsing the results, but I wonder if there is an existing utility that can take a list of shared libraries and topologically sort them for me, to give me an easy load order.

I have looked into the `lorder` command, but I think this is only designed for static libraries (?), and also `ar -ts`, but I think this has the same problem. If I am wrong, feel free to correct me.

Is there any common Linux utility that will give me a linking order for these shared objects? I'm on CentOS 7 by the way.

Comment: Do you have the option to load with flag `RTLD_LAZY` mentioned in `man dlopen`? (I don't know if that is sufficient though).

Comment: I believe R does use `dlopen`, but neither the `RTLD_LAZY` variable, nor the `now = FALSE` argument to the function seem to matter.